# Effect of an electromagnetic field on an open metallic body

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, electric-current, conductors

I have read on my book (I do not put its title since it is not in English) the following sentence about a metal body which receives an external electromagnetic wave (with Js we mean its current surface density):

> If the conductor surface S is open, the normal component of Js at the edges of S vanishes (Js is the vectorial sum of the surface currents on opposite sides of S) since no charge may accumulate at the edges.

I do not understand clearly it. Precisely:

1) I'd say that Js = 0 at the edges because they are an open circuit: current stops because the other medium is a dielectric (air or vacuum), in which current cannot flow. I do not understand the statement about charge accumulation.

2) I do not understand why only the normal component of Js vanishes at the edges, while the tangential component not.

Comment: To better understand your question, can you clarify what it means by "conductor surface S is *open*"?

Comment: I think it means it is an open surface, i.e. it has a certain boundary